# Yii2 UrlManager rule for tabular parameters

Tags: yii, yii2, friendly-url, pretty-urls

can I prettify tabular parameter like the following:

```
http://start/compare?art[]=CG%20110142&art[]=CG%20110144
```

and make it look like:

```
http://start/compare/art/CG%20110142/art/CG%20110142
```

or:

```
http://start/compare/art/CG%20110142/CG%20110142
```

If yes, please help me with pattern.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 ['pattern'=>'start/compare/<art1>/<art2>', 'route'=>'start/compare'],
```

But you must separate two parameter art1 and art2.
Like

`http://start/compare?art1[]=CG%20110142&art2[]=CG%20110144`